# Do CloudFormation target name or resources?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am currently pending between using terraform and CloudFormation. 
There is a question I haven't seen the answer yet (or maybe, I just haven't found it yet).

In terraform, you give a precise name to everything. This will delete the targets with those names. 
But what about CF? If we already have an architecture in place and I want to add/delete an instance and use CF, how will this work? How will it know after which one to target?

I hope this question makes sense! I've already used terraform, but never before CloudFormation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFormation uses two mechanisms to identify its resources.  The CFN template has a list of resources it created, it uses the actual ID, not a pretty name, and CFN also tags the resources (that support tags) with the stack ID.

CFN cannot be used to delete the resources in a different stack, only the stack that created them can manage them.  Terraform allows you to import resources created by anything else into a new stack where they will be managed.

I used CFN for a year before converting to Terraform (also for a year now) and I'll never go back to CFN.  Terraform offers many advantages over CFN that make CFN really hard to use now.  Features such as plan before apply, re-usable modules, resource imports, granular output (CFN is mostly a black box), and generally faster AWS feature support (usually APIs are released at launch day and Terraform support follows soon after, /usually/ faster than CFN but not always).

Comment: As an example of TF supporting a feature before CFN: S3 Object Locking. CFN has zero support for tit. TF already does. The doesn side of TF is that is can not be imported into a AWS CFN dashboard, usage is CLI or bust.

Comment: I wish I could say that was a problem for me, but I used CI/CD pipelines to run CFN stacks so I was already used to a text based output (of course I'd use the CFN console for more detailed information).  The output from the Terraform CLI is very detailed and well laid out, it's easy to get the information you need and know exactly what's running during an apply operation.

Comment: That's EACTLY what I needed! thanks for the answer, a real help :)